# Why does Matrix#[] return nil for non existent colum and an exeption for non existent row?

Tags: ruby, matrix

I'm having trouble understanding this behaviour of the Ruby Matrix class, is it just an (ugly) implementation detail or am I missing something?

```
>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'matrix'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> m = Matrix[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
=> Matrix[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
irb(main):004:0> m[1,1]
=> 5
irb(main):005:0> m[1,10]
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> m[10,1]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/matrix.rb:261:in `[]'
        from (irb):6
        from c:/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in first case (1,10) the first index is applied to a Matrix (the same as to an Array) and the second is applied to row (again the same as to array). But in the second case (10,1) the first index is applied to array, but the second here is applied to `nil` (because there is no 10th row) - this raises exception.

Comment: Ok, so Matrix is a very thin layer on top of Array then, do you know of any other library wich works more consistently?

Comment: @krusty.ar, sorry, I didn't worked with it - I just see by exception message the analogy to 2-dimensional Array.